# Ionic 4 & 5, thermal printer library for Epson model, needs to have automatic printing in Android device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a thermal printer that needs to be connected into my Android device via WiFi connection. I need it to be automatically print whenever a button is triggered (without the printing dialog)

Currently, I am using Ionic 4, but I cannot find any library which supports ESC/POS language. Any library that I could use?

Note:
The following solution works for Ionic 4 and 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find the solution via TCP/IP port connection from ionic into my WiFi connected thermal printer

In order to create a TCP/IP socket connection from ionic, I used [sockets for cordova](https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova) and send byte into my thermal printer IP. Depending on each printer, each printer has different set of ESC command (CMIIW) which mean we still need to convert the byte code one by one and send them into the thermal printer.

Also, I have fork a repository https://www.npmjs.com/package/esc-pos-encoder-ionic which can be used as a wrapper to encode ESC command into byte code. Then the result can be sent into the printer using TCP/IP socket.

Hope this helps others too.

Demo source code: https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo

Comment: Great job with esc-post-encoder-ionic!
Could you share the code example of how you integrated sockets for cordova in your Ionic project?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the code anymore (that was my previous freelance project) but I have requested my friend to extract the file. Please check it out at https://github.com/randy161/Ionic-4-Socket-EscPos-Printer-Sample/blob/master/Sample/printer.service.ts

If you need more info, I can hel

Comment: I thank you very much for the link, it has helped me.
Your esc-post-encoder-ionic package also helped me a lot, I will try to make an ionic version for sockets-for-cordova.
If I stuck, can I ask you for help? so we can publish it.

Comment: Yup, Sure. Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Hey @Cheezey I'm currently interested in this. but the github link is broken. Do you have any repository related to this. Really hard to find information about thermal printers with Ionic...

Comment: Hello @Gonzalo I have created a demo ionic application. Check it out
https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo

Comment: @cheezey do you have demo versions of Bluetooth plugin..thanks

Comment: I recently developed printing via Bluetooth connection into 80mm thermal printer. Will update the demo repo soon.

Comment: @Cheezey thanks a lot...waiting fr that  also i have asked  bounty question ..Pls anwser if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552320/android-app-with-bluetooth-pos-printer-with-in-ionic-framework

Comment: Hello, sure. Sorry for the slight delay due to holiday, I can't really test it out. Maybe what I can do is upload the latest ionic demo with Bluetooth functionality so that you can try it :)